# Facing module error on /usr/bin/python while creating nginx container using Ansible-Container build

Tags: python, nginx, module, fatal-error, ansible-container

**Code :**
        Container.yml:
        version: '2'
        settings:
          conductor:
            base: centos:7
        services:
          ansible.nginx-container:
            from: "nginx:base"
            roles:
            - nginx_container
            ports:
            - "80:3000"
            user: root
            command: [nginx,-g,'daemon off']
        registries: {}
        **OS/Environment :**
           Ansible Container, version 0.9.2
             Linux, 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64, #1 SMP Mon Feb 29
       [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] /usr/bin/python

```
    **Commands Used**    
    sudo ansible-container --debug build    
    sudo ansible-container  --debug build --use-local-python    

   **Expected result:**    
    Image should be build successfully.    

    **Actual result:**
    Facing module error on /usr/bin/python path.
    Error Logs: fatal: [ansible.nginx-container]: FAILED! => {
        "changed": false,
        "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: not found\n",
        "module_stdout": "",
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
        "rc": 0
    }    

Please help on steps to resolve this issue.TIA
```